# Command line instruction parsing

Tags: php, regex, command-line-interface

I've been all over google and haven't been able to find a regex that would parse (correctly) CLI arguments.

Does anyone have in their code library such a thing?

Ideally it would parse all styles of arguments (i.e.: -v -abc --arg=val --arg="val1 val2" --arg "val")

Thanks!

P.S.: This would be used in PHP context (preg)

Comment: Not sure if this would help with this question, but try [RegexLib](http://regexlib.com). It's an inmense Regex library :)

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/Console_CommandLine/

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at PEAR's [Console_Getopt](https://pear.php.net/package/Console_Getopt) or the Zend Framework [Zend_Console_Getopt](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.console.getopt.html)

Your PHP version may have support for [getopt](http://php.net/getopt) as a built-in also.

Comment: actually it's not in PEAR anymore, it's a standard function

Comment: it is in PEAR, Seems SO does odd things with URLs containing underscores, have changed the link...

Answer (score 4):

[`getopt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)

Answer (score 0):

The [global $argv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) already parses the command line arguments automatically if you're running CLI. Also see: [Using PHP from the command line](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd let you know I found a solution.

http://nlindblad.org/2007/05/12/handling-command-line-arguments-in-php/